# Change default gender option in Magento

Tags: magento

In Magento, when a new customer is added (admin -> manage customers -> account information), in the gender field, `male` is showing as the default option. I want to how to show `female` as the default option.

Can anyone help me? What changes do I need to make and in which file?

Thanks for any help or suggestions,

Thanks,

RIcha

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: its Magento ver. 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/customer/widget/gender.phtml`.